# What kind of GNSS antenna is this?

Tags: antenna, identification, gps, gnss

I would like to know what types of GNSS antennas are on the images below (patch etc.) and also which one is better from the two (if any). They are being sold as "high precision" survey grade antennas.

Photos of antenna internals were send to me by the sellers. Antenna #2 looks like a stacked patch type but I can not recognize type for antenna #1.

Antenna #1 (Buestues/High Gain HG-GOYH7151)
[image: gnss antenna]
[image]
[image]

Datasheet #1

[image]

Antenna #2 (TOPGNSS/STOTON GN-GGB0710)
[image]
[image]

Datasheet #2 (dimensions include antenna housing)

[image]

Comment: From the specifications there seems little to differentiate.  The second has a wider LNA voltage range which may not matter but is lighter which may.  Both look pretty nice and would have cost 20 times more 20 years ago.

Comment: Antenna no2 looks like a Harxon inside.

Answer (score 1):

Metalized Patchs over Dielectric Substrate (MW dielectrics , low loss), EFFICIENCY is the KEY word here...Since ALL dielectris waste signal...Gain is small and a little beter on stacked patches